# SSIS script task error after deploying to SQL Server 2019: Failed to migrate scripts contained in the package to the VSTA 15.0 format

Tags: ssis, vsta

I have an SSIS package that is failing on a Script Task with this error message:

> Failed to migrate scripts contained in the package to the VSTA 15.0 format.

This package was running fine on SQL Server 2012. But we recently upgraded to SQL Server 2019 and when I deploy this package to this new server, I get the above error message. This package is deployed from Visual Studio Professional 2015.

Has anyone seen this error before. I Googled this error but the discussions I found are very confusing. Would someone be able to help me figure this out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have no particular insight into this error, but it seems there's an issue with script compatibility that the deployment wizard couldn't automatically resolve. Q1 - Does the package use the Project Deployment Model (deployed to the SSISDB) or does it use the Package Deployment Model (deployed to the file system/SSIS Package Store or the msdb)? VS 2015 - I don't recall whether you could target different versions of the SSIS/SQL Server but I'd be surprised as to whether you could specify 2019 given the newness of it.

Comment: I would grab a copy of 2019 and install the Integration Services bits and try the deploy from there (after specifying that this package/project should target v2019). You might also "edit" the script with no material change like adding a comment. That should force the stored bytecode to get updated and that might smooth out the deploy.  Otherwise, I'd look to add more detail to your question - Script Task or Script Component? What is the code itself? Do other packages fail to deploy or just this one?

Comment: I've found that just opening the script task and script, build it, close it, save it will solve the problem. also redeploy it

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. I am about to upgrade my Visual Studio to something later than 2015 and deploy from there and see what happens.

Comment: Also, to the person that asked where is it deployed... It is deployed to SSISDB. In the current version of Visual Studio I am using, I see that it lets me change the deployment target version but the latest I can change to looks to be 2016. So I think I should try getting the latest version of Visual Studio and deploy the package from there and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. You have to change the TargetServerVersion to the version of SQL Server you are running.

Configuthe VS Solution explorer, R-Click on the project and select 'Properties'. Under on Properties of the solu> General need to change the TargetServerVersion to 2019.SQL Server; if that is the version of SQL You are running.